# Problem on calculating conditional expectation by law of total expectation

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

> Let $X$ be a standard normal distribution and let
> $$ Y= \begin{cases}X-1 & , X\le 0 \\ 
>     X &, X>0 \end{cases}$$
> Find mean and variance of $Y$.

MY working

$$E(Y)=E(X-1\mid X\le 0)P(X\le 0)+E(X\mid X>0)P(X>0)$$

Now $E(Y)$ is $-\frac12$.

For variance

$$E((X-1)^2\mid X\le 0)P(X\le 0) +E(X^2\mid X>0)$$

But am unable to calculate $-2E(X\mid X\le 0)$

help!

Comment: Please format your mathematics using LaTeX.

Comment: MathJax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is self-study (please tag and research!) I won't give you the answer, but the simple formula you are missing is the law of total variance:

$$\text{var}(X) = E(\text{var}(X|W)) + \text{var}(E(X|W))$$

Comment: Yes got it  thanks